# Special Ascii characters are converted to HTML entities in regular expression PHP preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

There is a simple regular expression which replaces semicolon from string with "*"

`preg_replace('/\;/', '*', $string);`

But if I use "♠♣♥♦" characters as string it converts it to HTML code: `&#9824;&#9827;&#9829;&#9830;` and then replace ";" with "*", so output is `♠*♣*♥*♦*`

How can I stop this characters from being converting to HTML codes?

Comment: Where does `$string` come from?

Comment: it is from form field, post variable

Comment: Are you doing a html_encode or similar on `$string` before `preg_replace`? I've tested your replace here and everything is OK.

Comment: No, I am not using html_encode or any other html functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip html entities with this kind of pattern:

```
$result = preg_replace('~&(?:#[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+);(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;~', '*', $text);
```

`&(?:#[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+);` describes html entities.

The `(*SKIP)` verb forces the substring matched on the left to not be retried (to be skipped) if the pattern fails later. `(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail.

In this way the second alternative (so `;`) is never a part of an html entity.

An other possible way consists to convert all html entities before, to perform the replacement with `strtr($text, ';', '*')` and to convert special characters to html entities again.

Comment: you understand it wrong. Actually I am giving "♠♣♥♦" as string and they are converted to HTML code before preg_replace. So even there is no ";" in string it is replaced. I want to stop this conversion

Comment: @user1531437: I understand it well. When someone take the time to give you an answer, please take the time to try/understand/read? it.

Comment: if you understand it well than how above regular expression HTML code conversion in preg_match. Your given regex is for stop the html code